# Showing the boundary of set has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose

$$ D = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: 0 \leq x \leq 1 , \; x^2 \leq y \leq x, \; \; 0 \leq z \leq x \} $$

I want to show $\partial D $ has measure zero.

My approach: I know that $D$ lies inside $Q = [0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1] $.

Can I say that $\partial D \subset \partial Q $ ?

$\mathbf{Update}$: Let $G_1 = \{ (x,y) : y = x \} $, $G_2 = \{ (x,y) : y = x^2 \} $, and $G_3 = \{ (x,y,z) : z = x \} $. We know $G_i$ have measure zero since they are graphs of continuous functions. Then

$$ \partial Q \cup \partial G_1 \cup \partial G_2 \cup \partial G_3   $$

has measure zero and since

$$ \partial D \subset \partial Q \cup \partial G_1 \cup \partial G_2 \cup \partial G_3 $$

then $\partial D $has measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are points in $\partial D$ that ar not in $\partial Q$. And in fact it is possible to exhibit sets $D'$ with $D'\subset Q$ and $\mu(\partial D')>0$.

Comment: how about if i take the union of $\partial Q $ with the graph of $z = x $ ?

Comment: ... and the graph $y=x$ and the graph $y=x^2$ (and you need only $x=0$, $x=1$, $z=0$ as parts of $\partial Q$)

Comment: See my update to my question. Is my claim correct?